# Stop google map idle event listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am using google 'idle' event listener to upload markers on map (with angularjs). My code is

```
$scope.LoadSearchPropertyOnPortFolioSales = function (PropertyName) {

 if(PropertyName == ''){
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
            var PropertyList = PropertyService.GetSearchPropertyForPortfolio($scope.PortfolioId, $scope.PropertyName, this.center.lat(), this.center.lng(), 0.005, 0.005);
                     PropertyList.then(function (pl) {
                         DrawPropertyOnPortFolioSale(pl.data, $scope.PropertyName);
                     },
             });
 }

 else 
 {
     //Stop event listener
 }
}
```

I want the event listener only work when PropertyName that is passed have no value. But when PropertyName have some value in it i want to stop event listener. How do i stop event listener......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also a function which removes all of the listeners at the same time:

```
clearListeners(instance:Object, eventName:string);
//In your case:
google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'idle');
```

[Here's the Google Maps API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#MapsEventListener) where you can read about it.